# Eclipse not packing class files into apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have searched stackoverflow for a question like mine but most of the questions I found involve a failed external jar library import into the apk.

My issue is a little bit different. My actual project source isn't being packaged into the apk, instead it is being compiled into a folder next to it and not in the package itself. I also have been searching in the build path options for a solution but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: When your project is build, you will find a classes/ folder and a classes.dex beside the apk in the project's bin/ directory, but there should also be a classes.dex inside the apk if you examine it using a zip file parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, i had created the library project as a android project instead of a java project. Silly mistake on my part

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are using "java perspective" in Eclipse.
Normally you can find your apk after compiling in "bin" under "package explorer" in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

to pack your app you have to right click on your project then 
Android Tools --> Export Signed Application
then set up a key and password

maybe you did this wrong...?

Comment: i am doing this correctly the same is happening when i use the debugger. their is a file called classes.dex is it maybe packaging the classes into their ?

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\[YourUserName]\.android\
```

Delete cache folder and ddms.cfg file. it Will probably solve most of the Eclipse Related problems. (Atleast it works for me) :P